# unable to use liquibase standalone shell script

Tags: java, liquibase

(Sharing my own workaround via Q/A)

I was getting the following error while trying to run liquibase as a standalone shell script, from the `liquibase-3.6.2-bin.tar.gz` release:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
█
```

After some googling and inspecting the `liquibase` shell script, I downloaded jars for these two projects:

- https://logback.qos.ch/download.html
- https://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Then I created a `./lib` directory relative to where the `liquibase` lives and symlinked into it the following jars:

- logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
- logback-core-1.2.3.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar

After these steps the command line liquibase worked.

I agree with these points made by one of the posters in [this thread](http://%20http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/unable-to-launch-liquibase-using-command-line), sinc currently would be difficult to use liquibase as a standalone utility:

> 1) This release is missing a required library to be self-sufficient.
>    2) Further more: The packaging of the Liquibase jar should switch from utilizing a lib/ folder to being an Uber jar with all required
>   libs included.

There appears to be a [bug report](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3201) for the same issue in 3.6.0, but at least for me in 3.6.2 it has not been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling and inspecting the liquibase shell script, I downloaded jars for these two projects:

- https://logback.qos.ch/download.html
- https://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Then I created a ./lib directory relative to where the liquibase lives and symlinked into it the following jars:

- logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
- logback-core-1.2.3.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar

After these steps the command line liquibase worked.

I agree with these points made by one of the posters in this thread, since currently it would be difficult to use liquibase as a standalone utility:

> 1) This release is missing a required library to be self-sufficient.
>   2) Further more: The packaging of the Liquibase jar should switch from
>   utilizing a lib/ folder to being an Uber jar with all required libs
>   included.

There appears to be a bug report for the same issue in 3.6.0, but at least for me in 3.6.2 it has not been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

liquibase has dependencies, it's normal.

you can build an uberjar or build a lib folder (containing the needed dependencies) with you build tool, aka maven or gradle.

moreover, it allows you to package a script script to launch the database update from command line, in Zip format for example.

Comment: the standalone shell script appears to be intended to be self-sufficient, and it looks for the lib/ directory to enhance the classpath, but there are missing dependencies in this release as described, see https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3222

Comment: i thought a homemade archive build by mvn/gradle, to get all needed dependencies

Comment: users of the liquibase cli may not necessarily be using java in their own development stack

Comment: whatever the tool, more important is to integrate the liquibase call to the build tool

Comment: yes. but there's no need to assume the build tool is mvn/gradle, it may be a simple shell script for a non-java app, which shouldn't be burdened with packaging liquibase dependencies.