# Liquibase: update throwing sl4j.Logger class not found exception

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to run `liquibase update` in `Windows` by providing the details such as classpath, dialect,url,user, password and I am getting an `sl4j.Logger` class not found exception.

The command looks like this

```
java -jar liquibase.jar update --classpath=mypath ...
```

The `sl4j` jar is present in the `lib` package of my liquibase.

What should I do to solve the error.

The error log is as follows:-

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at 
liquibase.logging.core.Slf4JLoggerFactory.getLog(Slf4JLoggerFactory.java:9)
        at liquibase.logging.LogService.getLog(LogService.java:39)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

When I try to run through bat file with the command

```
liquibase update --changeLogFile=C:\Desktop\migrate\update-test\changelog\databasechangelog.xml --driver=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect --classpath=C:\Desktop\migrate\update-test\postgresql --url=jdbc:postgresql://myserver:5432/  --username=postgres  --password=postgres --logLevel=debug
```

, I am getting unexpected params error

```
 unexpected command parameters: [--changeLogFile=C:Desktop\migrate\update-test\changelog\databasechangelog.xml, --driver=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, --classpath=C:\migrate\update-test\postgresql, --url=jdbc:postgresql://myserver.COM:5432/, --username=postgres, --password=postgres]
```

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, it is helpful if you include the full error in your question.

That said, you might be seeing the same thing as in this question: [unable to use liquibase standalone shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470254/unable-to-use-liquibase-standalone-shell-script)

Comment: I have added the log